# In App Purchase Subscription from App Store Swift iOS

Tags: uikit, in-app-purchase, app-store, storekit2

I built an app which has subscription. I am trying to implement apple pay for the subscription. It has monthly and yearly subscription options. I have implemented StoreKit frame for test purpose and it works as expected.

I then tried to do the same subscription on appstore and followed the documentations from apple. But when I upload it to appstore for testing, then product id could not be found. Everything work fine.

If anyone experienced the issue, please share your advice. I am really looking for some help. Thanks in advance.